# How do I make tab key work within this dialog control?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I added `IsDialogMessage()` to my main loop, the tab key did work but it stuck at the top of the tab control and didn't go down to the controls inside the dialog box. How can I fix that? I've tried `WS_GROUP` in the first control and `WS_TABSTOP` all the next created controls but it didn't work.

The tab control is created like this:

```
hTabControl =
          CreateWindowW(WC_TABCONTROLW, NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT,
            10, 30, 400, 250,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU) ID_MAIN_TABCONTROL,
            NULL,
            NULL);
```

and the dialog box:

```
      CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT,
            "DialogBox",
            L"Dialog Box",
            WS_SYSMENU | WS_CHILD | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE,
            10, 30, 350, 150,
            hTabControl, NULL, ghInstance,  NULL
      );

      // ...

  WNDCLASSEXW wc = {0};
  wc.cbSize           = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
  wc.lpfnWndProc      = DialogProc;
  wc.hInstance        = ghInstance;
  wc.hbrBackground    = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpszClassName    = "DialogClass";
  RegisterClassExW(&wc);
```

then the DialogProc procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(msg)
  {
  
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowW(L"button", L"A",
          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP,
          50, 50, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TAB1_BUTTONA, NULL, NULL);  
        CreateWindowW(L"button", L"B", 
          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
          150, 50, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TAB1_BUTTONB, NULL, NULL);
        CreateWindowW(L"button", L"C",
          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
          250, 50, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TAB1_BUTTONC, NULL, NULL);
        CreateWindowW(L"button", L"D",
          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
          50, 100, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TAB1_BUTTOND, NULL, NULL);
        CreateWindow(L"Edit", NULL,
          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,
          150, 100, 80, 20, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TAB1_EDIT1, NULL, NULL);
    break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
          // didn't do anything
          default: 
          break;

          case ID_TAB1_BUTTONA:
          {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Click on A button", L"Welcome to the jungle!", MB_OK);
          }
          break;
        }

    break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;

  }
  
  return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And the main loop:

```
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
      if (!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg)) {
          TranslateMessage(&msg);
          DispatchMessage(&msg);
      }
```

}

Comment: Why does your (inner) dialog have the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style?

Comment: I guess that was left out on my attempt to hide the tab control from ALT+TAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't create interactive windows/controls as children of the tab control, strange but true. Create the inner dialog as a child of the outer dialog, not the tab control.

[This MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-tabbed-dialog-box) creates the inner dialogs as children of the main dialog.

As explained [in this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191015-00/?p=102996), `WS_EX_CONTROL­PARENT` takes the window/control out of the tab order.

This is a pure Win32 thing, Delphi/C++Builder and other environments with custom UI toolkits often implement the tab control as a real container.

Comment: That's really strage, I came from C#'s world so I was trying to emulate what I thought was the proper behavior, making those windows tab control's children. But reading Raymond's blog post I see why it's so and how common is to make that mistake. In order to make those controls tab control's siblings, I changed to `CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT,... , hwnd)` in the windows procedure `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { ... } `. Is that correct now? I wasn't aware of `WS_EX_CONTROL­PARENT` take tab of order, removed that

Comment: With this dialog, I was trying to emulate a container with WINAPI, as I didn't find anything like this in the WINAPI. But how it's usually done with WINAPI it's topic to another question. The tab keys is working fine now I combined those with `WS_GROUP` in the first control followed by `WS_TABSTOP` in all the subsequent windows created in the procedure. Is this the way tabbing is done with WINAPI?

Comment: You generally only use the group style with radio buttons, that is the only place they are required. Other places are just to support arrow keys navigation if you use the group style. For normal controls you normally just use tabs top on each.

Comment: I see, removed the WS_GROUP then. What I read is misleading.

Comment: but the way I'm creating those controls, is the right way to go?

Comment: Don't use WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT on controls, just WS_TABSTOP. WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT is for the inner dialog.

Comment: I removed this, thanks. I was asking about using dialog window as tab page for the tab control. It isn't as tab control are created with WINAPI? Is this a good practice?

Comment: Yes, using one child dialog per tab page is normal practice.